# Best way to connect multiplayer users with each other (matchmaking) on a low powered server?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, server, online

OK so I am using unity to make a multiplayer game, but I'm not sure how to connect players with each other over the internet.

Unlike other questions, this isn't a general problem of working out how to do UPnp or using unity's matchmaking server. My issue is that my server that I would use is a simple low powered pc (running normal windows 10, no idea how to use windows server).

I think it is powerful enough to match players with each other, but not to host more than one or two actual games.

The other issue is that I have a residential internet connection with a dynamic ip that changes every few months. However the speed should be ok (150Mb/s download, 20Mb/s download).

Also, I'm not planning to spend money on a monthly basis for a server (like unity's matchmaking service) as I plan to spend as little as possible (So far I've paid £12 to Microsoft for a dev account and I've received a £200 voucher from them so my current spending is -£189!)

So my question is should I use my server (would it work), are there any online services that are very cheap to use, or is there another way to make this work?

Only other thing is I could use the free 20 users at once on unity's matchmaking, but would this limit be too small?

EDIT:
just for information, my game is a simple tank shooter. I was thinking about limiting the amount of tanks in a game somewhere around 8-20. The bullets in my game are physical objects with rigidbodys and they move at a slower speed (if you've ever played tank trouble, it looks like that). The world is in 3D. There is a potential for there to be up to a hundred bullets in a scene at once at the worst.
After hosting a LAN world with 7 players connected for about 20-30 minutes, windows reports the data usage being around 3-4MB.

Comment: What if your game becomes successful? Plan for that. You'll need to spend money for hosting your servers eventually, if only to mitigate DoS attacks on your server.

Comment: Well, hopefully if my game becomes successful, I would earn enough from it to either upgrade my server or use an online tool.

Comment: You mention that you expect your home server to be able to host only 1-2 games at a time, which puts it in the same rough range of simultaneous users as Unity's free offering. In a scenario like that, I don't really see any benefit to using your own server - especially since it has a dynamic IP so you'd need to couple it with a web service that clients could query to find out where to actually contact it (which will be another cost if you don't already have web hosting somewhere). It's a pile of extra complexity for relatively little gain and terrible scalability.

Comment: @JoeSpeers did you get the answer of your question?

Comment: I guess the best way to purchase this https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/58948 or this https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/58179

Comment: port forwarding technique can be used to do this task.

Comment: Yes, that looks really good. If my usage gets high enough I will consider buying it but it seems a little expensive!
However I may be able to receive some unity asset store credit for free from windows dev benefits so I may get it then.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go the home server route.  The hassle and reliablity problems (dynamic IP, power, etc.) aren't worth it.

- Get yourself a small VPS for a fiver per month.
- Amazon's AWS offers (or used to at least) a micro instance free  for the first year
- Google's app engine (applicable if you implement the matchmaking service on one of their supported platforms) has a fairly generous free quota if I'm not mistaken.

Implementing a matchmaking service, which lets the player's connect to each other (i.e. isn't running the game itself) shouldn't require much resources, nor would it require a specific OS.

The above suggestions are also easy to scale if your game takes off.